# How to remove an element from a list x amount of times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to remove a number by an x amount of times from a list. For example, for this list `[1, 4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 8, 11]` if I wanted to remove the integer 4 by 2 times, the list would look like this: `[1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 4, 8, 11]`. What code would be efficient in this situation?
The code I have in the moment:

```
int_list = [1, 4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 8, 11]
result = []
remove = int(input('remove: '))
times = int(input('times: '))
for i in int_list:
    if i != remove:
        result.append(i)
elements = result
print(elements)
```

Comment: Should it return a new list or manipulate the same one? What would happen if you put, let's say, 8 by 2 times (it only appears once)? Should it be an error?

Comment: The only rules are:
1- The code must print a list
2- if times == 0, print original list
3- That's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Working in-place

The list method [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) removes the first occurrence of the argument from the list. So you can simply call it `x` amount of times on the list:

```py
int_list = [1, 4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 8, 11]
remove = 4
times = 2
for _ in range(times):
    int_list.remove(remove)
print(int_list)
```

Will give:

```
[1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 4, 8, 11]
```

#### Handling errors

In case the element is not found, `remove` will raise an error. If you want to avoid that:

- Check the input pre-hand by making sure there are enough elements to remove using the [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) method:

  ```
  if int_list.count(remove) <= times:
     # rest of code
  ```
- If you want to just remove all possible elements, add a check before the `remove` call:

  ```
  for _ in range(times):
      if remove in int_list:
          int_list.remove(remove)
  ```

### Returning a new list

You can of course simply create a copy of the input list (`res = int_list.copy()`) and then apply the in-place solution from above. Otherwise, to create a completely new list, use `times` as a counter for how many times to *"skip"* the wanted number:

```py
int_list = [1, 4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 8, 11]
remove = 4
times = 2
res = []
for num in int_list:
    if num == remove and times > 0:
        times -= 1
        continue
    res.append(num)
print(res)
```

In this case there is no error handling to make. We are simply ignoring the required element a given amount of times. If it doesn't exist at all, less, or more times than given - nothing will happen.